# Simple MySQL question - MAX(field)?

Tags: sql, mysql, max

Hi just a simple question
I know how to get the most recurring field from a table

```
SELECT MAX(field) FROM table
```

But how do I get the Second most recurring field from a table?

Thank you.

Comment: Wait a sec ... but if the field is INT the MAX(field) will catch the HIGHER number or the most found ?

Comment: `MAX()` finds the highest number (i.e. the maximum).

Comment: There's a function to get the MOST FOUND ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    field,
    COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY field
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1, 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do that using `LIMIT` to set an offset.

```
 SELECT field FROM table ORDER BY field DESC LIMIT 1,1;
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I'll try that in a second !!

Answer (score 2):

If performance is crucial for you, this can help to avoid sorting:

```
SET @a := (SELECT MAX(field) FROM table);
SELECT MAX(field) FROM table WHERE field != @a;
```

As alternative you can store @a value in code.

Comment: That is great !
I was not aware of that @syntax.

Just another small question but if the field is INT. The MAX() function will catch up the HIGHER number or the MOST FOUND ?
     
Thank you Vitalii

Answer (score 1):

Definition ([from about.com](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)): Limit is used to limit your MySQL query results to those that fall within a specified range. You can use it to show the first X number of results, or to show a range from X - Y results. It is phrased as Limit X, Y and included at the end of your query. X is the starting point (remember the first record is 0) and Y is the duration (how many records to display).
Also Known As: Range Results
Examples:

```
 SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

will display the first 10 results from the database.

```
 SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5
```

will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10

```
 SELECT * FROM `your_table` ORDER BY 'FIELD' DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

will show the second most recurring record